# Left and right arrows do not fade out when moved out of the image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to web development and needed to provide navigating to images with left and right arrows. I need the arrows to fade in when the mouse is hovered over the image and fade out when moved out of the image. I can see the arrows fade in but not fade out. Somewhere near the image tip I see a small flicker but not really the fadeout and fade in as I hover in and out of the images. I tried to change the opacity to 1 and 0 as suggested by related articles in stackoverflow but it doesnt seem to work. Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong?Any help is appreciated?

Here is a sample html:

```
<div id="centralcontent">
    <div id="slideshow">
            <ul id="nav">
               <li id="prev"><a href="#"></a></li>
               <li id="next"><a href="#"></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="slides">               
              <img src="images/nature/imageone.jpg" width="1200" height="750">
            </div>           
    </div>              
</div>
```

The CSS is :

```
#centralcontent
{
    padding-top:40px;        
}
#slideshow {
   width:1200px;
   height:750px;
   padding: 15px 0 0 12px;
   margin: 0 auto;  
   position: relative; 
   z-index: 5;
   margin-bottom:0px;
}
#slideshow ul#nav
{
   display: none;
   list-style: none;
   position: relative;
   top: 300px;
   z-index: 10;
 }
 #slideshow ul#nav li#prev  
 {
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
 }
 #slideshow ul#nav li#next
 {
    float: right; 
    margin: 0 50px 0 0;
 }
 #slideshow ul#nav li a
 {
    display: block;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;      
  }
  #slideshow ul#nav li#prev a {
    border-top: 40px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right: 40px solid gray;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
   }
   #slideshow ul#nav li#next a {
     border-top: 40px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 40px solid transparent;
     border-left: 40px solid gray;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
  }
  #slides {
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  }
```

My javascript is :

```
$(document).ready(function() {        
  $("#slideshow").hover(function() {
   $("ul#nav").fadeIn("slow");
     },function() {
    $("ul#nav").fadeOut("slow");
   });     
});
```

Comment: Works here with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/d1vsm3xz/

Comment: Oh, it doesnt work on my machine at all..Just a note.. I tried uploading my page to a server and could see it work on IE and firefox but not on chrome. However locally it worked on none of the browsers. Any clue?

Answer (score 0):

You code seems to work for me here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1vsm3xz/)

However, I would recommend using a CSS only approach. Instead of giving the arrows `display: none;`, give them an opacity of zero and transition that to full opacity when the wrap is hovered:

[CSS Only Approach - JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d1vsm3xz/1/)

```
ul#nav {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 1s;
}
#slideshow:hover ul#nav {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will give this a try too. I am not sure why the fadeout doesnt work on my machine. Do you have any clue why this behaviour could be browser specific ?

Comment: I'm not sure. Either way, I would still recommend using the CSS solution.